# hdparm error "Invalid exchange"

Tags: hard-drive, ubuntu-10.04

Since my upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10 (from 9.04), the following error occurs:

```
bronger@wilson:/$ sudo hdparm -q -S 3 /dev/sdc
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(setidle) failed: Invalid exchange
```

This used to work before.  The drive is not mounted in the filesystem.  I haven't changed the hardware configuration.  Even the partitioning is the same.  It still works with another harddisk (sdb).

What does this error mean and what can I do about it?